# Skip layouSubviews for hidden views

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Due to designer for an app I'm working on, I have to cram a lot of things into one view controller. I figured I would lessen some CPU strain and save some time by skipping on calling

```
[super layoutSubviews];
```

on hidden views (and be view**s** I mean a subclass of UIView that holds all other stuff) and only refresh it before view is going to appear. If it matters to some of you, I do this by setting BOOL flag. This works fine on iOS8 but crashes app on iOS7 with:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. XXX's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

So how can I skip calling layoutSubviews on iOS7?

Of course, there is this possibility that I completely don't understand how iOS works and skipping this call doesn't save any time because it calculates constraints anyway. In that case, the question would be 'how can I skip calculating constraints for hidden views?'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were dropping iOS 7 support, iOS 8 adds the ability to disable and enable constraints via the `active` property. But If you need to support iOS 7, your only option is to remove the views and/or constraints from the view hierarchy, and reinstate them when you need them again.

But are you sure that `-layoutSubviews` is causing a slowdown? You should run something like the Time Profiler in Instruments to make sure that really is the problem, before trying to optimize it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to support iOS7. Well, it's not causing slowdowns **now** but it's still pretty early in development and there will be more things and I know that autolayout gets slower with more things to layout. Maybe I'm just paranoid and too eager but it just rubs me the wrong way when system wastes some time calculating unnecessary things :P Well, but that's a shame, if no one will provide contradictory answer to you, I will accept it sometime next week.